# Scrapy: How to store scraped data in different json files within one crawler run?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using generic spiders with a list of multiple urls in the `start_urls` field.

Is it possible to export one `json` file for each URL?

As far as I know it's only possible to set one path to one specific output file.

Any ideas how to solve this are rewarded!

EDIT: This is my spider class:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my_spider'
    start_urls =  start_urls = ['www.domain1.com','www.domain2.com', 
   'www.domain3.com']


    custom_settings = {
                'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
                'DEPTH_LIMIT': '1',
                'FEED_URI': 'file:///C:/path/to/result.json',
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"abc"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        all_text = response.xpath("//p/text()").getall()

        yield {
            "text": " ".join(all_text),
            "url": response.url,
        }
```

Comment: you would have to create own class `Pipeline` with `process_item()` which save `item` in different files. It may need to sed url with `item`

Comment: example Pipeline which saves items with different caterogies in different files - it uses value from `item` to select filename: [furas / python-examples / scrapy / save-categories-in-separated-files](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/scrapy/save-categories-in-separated-files/category/pipelines.py)

Comment: you can also run three separated crawlers with different domains and differents files.

Comment: documentation shows similar Pipeline in [Item Exporters](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html)

Comment: Okay, it seems that it's definitely possible. That's good to know. I am thinking about the best approach for my spider. If have added it to my original post, so it is easier to talk about what is the prefered option.

Comment: I see you aready get answer with code - and both versions seem OK. Use version which you like.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71679403/how-to-export-scraped-data-as-readable-json-using-scrapy. I raised a follow-up question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### First option

You can save the items in the spider as [Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider) for example:

```
import scrapy
import json

DICT = {
    'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/': 'domain1.json',
    'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/': 'domain2.json',
}


class MydomainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mydomain"
    start_urls = [
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = DICT[response.url]
        with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
            json.dump({"content": response.body.decode("utf-8")}, fp)
```

The `DICT` variable is just for specifying the JSON filename but you can use the domain as the filename too.

### Second option

You can try using `process_item` in `pipelines.py` as follow:

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter


class SaveJsonPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       filename = item['filename']
       del item['filename']
       JsonItemExporter(open(filename, "wb")).export_item(item)
       return item
```

`item['filename']` is for save the filename for each `start_url`. You need to set the `items.py` too, for example:

```
import scrapy


class MydomainItem(scrapy.Item):
    filename = scrapy.Field()
    content = scrapy.Field()
```

your spider:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import MydomainItem


DICT = {
    'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/': 'domain1.json',
    'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/': 'domain2.json',
}


class MydomainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mydomain'
    allowed_domains = ['mydomain.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MydomainItem()
        item["filename"] = DICT[response.url]
        item["content"] = response.body.decode("utf-8")
        yield item
```

Before running you need to add the pipeline in your settings.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.SaveJsonPipeline': 300,
}
```

Comment: I am pretty new to Scrapy and all my spiders don't use ```Scrapy.Item``` and ```Scrapy.Field```. Do you know how your solution would look like when using ```yield``` without ```Scrapy.Item```and ```Scrapy.Field```?

Comment: Plase have a quick look at my edit in my original post. I added some more information.

Comment: @Daniel You can use normal dictionary `item = dict()` instead of `item = MydomainItem()` - and it still should work

Comment: @Daniel you can use a normal dictionary as @furas said. You can change `item = MydomainItem()` to `item={}` and all works OK too.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71679403/how-to-export-scraped-data-as-readable-json-using-scrapy. I raised a follow up question.