# How to export scraped data as readable json using Scrapy

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy

According to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71507177/11934963) I wrote a spider to save each domain to a separate json file. I have to use `CrawlSpider` to use `Rules` for visiting sublinks.

But the file contains `json` data that cannot be read by `pandas`. It should have a nice and readable new line separated json. But Scrapy expects the exported json to be byte like.

[image]

The desired output format is:

```
{"content": "text", "scrape_date": "36456456456"}
{"content": "text", "scrape_date": "56445435435"}
```

My spider.py:

```
import scrapy
import time
import json
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from urllib.parse import urlparse


DICT = {
    'quotes.toscrape.com': 'domain1.json',
    'stadt-koeln.de': 'domain2.json',
}


class PagingIncremental(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my_spider"

    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com', 'stadt-koeln.de']

    start_urls = [
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'https://www.stadt-koeln.de/leben-in-koeln/planen-bauen/bebauungsplaene/aufstellen-eines-bauleitplanes'
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': '0',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': '1',
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': 'True',
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': '1',
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': '3'
    }
    # Visit all found sublinks
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r""), callback='parse', follow=False),
    )

    def parse(self, response):

        item = {}

        # get domain from each sub page 
        domain = urlparse(response.url).netloc
        domain = domain.replace("www.", "")

        # if domain from DICT above matches with domain from subpage
        # all sublinks are stored in the same output file
        item["filename"] = DICT[domain]
        item["content"] = response.xpath("//p/text()").getall() 
        item['scrape_date'] = int(time.time())

        yield item


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    })

    # process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(PagingIncremental)
    process.start()
```

My `pipelines.py`:

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter

class SaveJsonPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        filename = item['filename']
        del item['filename']

        # if the file exists it will append the data 
        JsonItemExporter(open(filename, "ab")).export_item(item)

        return item
```

My `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   '<project_name>.pipelines.SaveJsonPipeline': 300,
}
```

If I use `a` instead of `ab` to export the data in `pipelines.py`in non-binary format Scrapy says:

```
 JsonItemExporter(open(filename, "a")).export_item(item)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 135, in export_item
    self.file.write(to_bytes(data, self.encoding))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Any ideas and solutions are awarded!

Comment: it is NOT JSON but multi(line)-JSON (also know as JSONL) and Pandas may have problem to read it.

Comment: if you don't use `b` then it automatically use `text mode` and it needs `strings` but you could use `.encode('utf-8')` to convert bytes to string

Comment: if you want JSONL then maybe use [JsonLinesItemExporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#jsonlinesitemexporter). But if you want normal JSON then you may need to get all items on list and then write all at once using `JsonItemExporter`

Comment: I am struggling how to combine the creation of multiple json files like in the example above and using ```JsonLinesItemExporter``` together. If you have an working example, probably that would be the solution.

Comment: Not sure where to use ```.encode('utf-8')``` in line ```JsonItemExporter(open(filename, "ab")).export_item(item)```. The ```JsonItemExporter```doesn't seem very flexible to change the code.

Comment: I wouldn't bother bytes - even documentation mentions that it has to open file in `bytes mode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [JsonLinesItemExporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#jsonlinesitemexporter) instead of `JsonItemExporter` to get every item in separated line.

And don't bother `bytes` because documentation mentions that it has to open file in `bytes mode`.

And in [pandas.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) you can use option `lines=True` to read `JSONL` (multiline-JSON):

```
df = pd.read_json('domain1.json', lines=True)
```

---

**Full working code.**

All code is in one file so everyone can simply copy and test it.

I used `'__main__.SaveJsonPipeline'` to load class from current file.

I also added code to remove spaces in `content` and join in one string:

```
" ".join([x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//p/text()").getall()]).strip()
```

---

```
import time
import scrapy
#import json
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter, JsonLinesItemExporter


class SaveJsonPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        filename = item['filename']
        del item['filename']

        # if the file exists it will append the data 
        JsonLinesItemExporter(open(filename, "ab")).export_item(item)

        return item


DICT = {
    'quotes.toscrape.com': 'domain1.json',
    'stadt-koeln.de': 'domain2.json',
}


class PagingIncremental(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my_spider"

    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com', 'stadt-koeln.de']

    start_urls = [
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'https://www.stadt-koeln.de/leben-in-koeln/planen-bauen/bebauungsplaene/aufstellen-eines-bauleitplanes'
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': '0',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': '1',
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': 'True',
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': '1',
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': '3'
    }
    # Visit all found sublinks
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r""), callback='parse', follow=False),
    )

    def parse(self, response):

        item = {}

        # get domain from each sub page 
        domain = urlparse(response.url).netloc
        domain = domain.replace("www.", "")

        # if domain from DICT above matches with domain from subpage
        # all sublinks are stored in the same output file
        item["filename"] = DICT[domain]
        #item["content"] = [x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//p/text()").getall()]
        item["content"] = " ".join([x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//p/text()").getall()]).strip()
        item['scrape_date'] = int(time.time())

        yield item


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.SaveJsonPipeline': 1},  # used Pipeline create in current file (needs __main___)
    })

    # process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(PagingIncremental)
    process.start()

    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_json('domain1.json', lines=True)
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: You are my scraping hero. Thank you so much. I would like to scrape around 10.000 different websites and I think this is a first step to make the spider more generic regarding broad crawling.

Comment: you can see code from some of my answers in [furas / python-examples / scraping](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)